# how can I block typing "qq.com" on the input tag?

Tags: input, block, spam

A spammer keeps sending spam mail with my email form.

The spammer types `qq.com` on the input tag, and I want to block `qq.com` on it.

Here is my code:

```
input type="email" class="text" name="i_mail" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" value=""
```

Please help me.

Comment: Thank you for the correction about english grammar.
Btw problem has solved.